# Preprocessing in C++

Tags: preprocessor

How to make that when I define both instructions at the same time I will get the compilation error?
Here I want error

```
#define ENG
#define POL
#if defined POL
#if defined ENG
```

Here not

```
#define ENG
//#define POL
#if defined POL
#if defined ENG
```

Comment: The question is not related to the C++ language. Therefore changed tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#if defined( ENG ) && defined( POL )
#error You can't define both!
#endif
```